# php pdo how time take the query

Tags: php, runtime, pdo

i am using php with pdo ,
when i run a mysql query, is this possible to get a value of the query time its take

i know i can do `microtime()` before and after, i want to know if there something build-in in the pdo.

thanks .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not without [extending](http://www.coderholic.com/php-database-query-logging-with-pdo/) the existing PDO implementation. There are a few [libraries](http://www.planet-source-code.com/URLSEO/vb/scripts/ShowCode!asp/txtCodeId!2710/lngWid!8/anyname.htm) which do this. However, I do not believe there is anything *within* the current implementation of PDO that can accomplish this.